# Bluetooth not connecting with Sharing enabled

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth

I have `CoreBluetooth` setup and it's working fine but when I enable Internet Sharing on my Mac the iOS app won't connect to my OSX app. Is this a limitation caused by `CoreBluetooth`?

Update (22-05-2014) :
Tested another app (iOS and OSX) that uses `CoreBluetooth` and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth is for Bluetooth Low Energy communication. What you are probably looking for is the PAN profile. To connect the Mac via iOS, you will need to enable Tethering. Then, you can probably use TCP sockets to talk with each other.